# Netbeans Codeigniter Code Templates

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

Is there any netbeans code templates available for codeigniter ?

Like : http://abechik.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/netbeans-php-code-template/

Comment: If you're a mac user just download text expander and you can create your own shortcuts http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](http://www.mybelovedphp.com/2009/01/23/netbeans-revisited-code-completion-for-code-igniter/), [this](https://github.com/ethaizone/Codeigniter-Templates-For-Netbeans) and [this](https://github.com/cfidecaro/CodeIgniter-Netbeans-Templates) from [google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=iceweasel-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&sa=X&ei=SX5fT5a0JsPVrQedkM2jBg&ved=0CB0QvwUoAQ&q=netbeans%20codeigniter%20template&spell=1&biw=1366&bih=478). Though I never really look into it, but I do keep the [source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter) and [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) in handy for reference as it is accurate as doubt arise during coding.